# Uploading a seemingly large (~200 GB) archive to Amazon Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I am seeking to upload a 200+ GB archive to Amazon Glacier—a single `.tgz`.

Wondering if anyone has had experience with this, and whether this seems extraordinary to accomplish without timeout issues, etc. On one hand, 200 GB is a lot of data. On the other hand, it appears Glacier is built to handle this type of demand.

I intend to use the Python `boto` library. Anyone have any recommendations otherwise?

Comment: Glacier is certainly able to handly your 200GB. All things considered, that's not all that much data. Your main issue will likely be your upstream bandwidth and the reliability of your internet connection. Make sure to use an upload method that will allow you to restart the transfer in the event of a connection issue.

Comment: To glacier that is tiny. The problem will be your connection. I woukd recommend reading the free ebook on amazon glacier deployment

Comment: Awesome. @t1nt1n. I will Google for that eBook. Fortunately, I pushed all my stuff to an EC2 instance, created the `.tgz` there, and will be moving to Glacier from there. Sounds good, right?

Comment: Its in the kindle store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, Glacier is more than able to handle 200GB of data.
(Frankly, in terms of *Big Data* 200GB is nothing - I routinely move backups that size every month.)

The two things to be aware of are your upstream connection limitations as was mentioned in the comments, and your need to ever get this data back (Glacier is really cheap to store to, but really expensive to retrieve from).
If you won't be hampered by either of those concerns (and a review of the [Glacier book/documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/glacier/) doesn't reveal any other trouble spots for your planned deployment) you should be fine.